# Shrinking debian partition with gnome-disks results in same size and more disk usage

Tags: partition, gnome-disks

I have a USB key with the following partitions:

- FAT EFI 300MB
- EXT4 Debian System 200GB (40GB used)
- FAT 16GB
- Swap 18GB (I think I should remove this partition anyway)

I decided to shrink the EXT4 Debian partition from 200GB to 60GB, using `gnome-disks`.

After a while the job seemed done but I think that something went wrong because now the partition is still 200GB and it seems that I only have 20GB of free space in that partition.

If I try to boot form the USB key, the Debian system of course works fine but it confirms that the partition is still 200GB and that there are only 20GB of free space left.

Giving that before the operation I had 40GB of used space, how this can be possible and how I can fix it?

**EDIT**

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    1 233,3G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    1 201,2G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    1  16,9G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    1  14,9G  0 part
```

**EDIT 2**

I resized again the partition with gnome-disks, this time restoring the original size (i ran the resize command with no resize to do at all), now the partition and the file system seems aligned

**EDIT 3**

Now I retried shrinking in two trances, the first by 64GB, the second 90GB, both worked and the Debian partition is now 60GB

I still wandering why this happened and how to prevent/fix by command line

Comment: looks like you shrink **filesystem** but not **partition**, what is the result of `lsblk` for the key ?

Comment: I added the result of lsblk. It is worth to notice that if I run `baobab` it says that the volume is 216GB but that there are 20.4GB available in 62.7GB total